# How can I remove all traces of Windows 8 Consumer Preview *downloader* from my system?

Tags: windows-8-preview, installer

Yesterday, on a whim, I decided to install Windows 8 Consumer Preview on an old netbook. Since the netbook was running ArchLinux, I decided to download the Windows 8 Preview setup application and create a bootable flash drive using that per what I believe is Microsoft's recommendation (rather than downloading the ISO directly).

Long story short, I noticed the download was taking way too long, so I closed the download window, deleted the temp directories, and deleted the downloaded set up application without much thought.

This morning, the download window popped up again. I can't see an entry in the "Add or Remove Programs" window for the Windows 8 Consumer Preview installer and there is nothing in scheduled tasks. Could you please tell me how to get rid of this downloader?

I am running Windows XP SP 3, in case that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the most recent invocation re-created the "Download Windows" icon on the desktop. Previously, I had <kbd>Shift-Del</kbd>eted the short-cut, but this time, I checked its properties. Turns out, the executable is `"C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\WebSetup\Sources\WebSetup.exe" /late`.

I zipped up the `WebSetup` directory and wiped it out. We'll see if something reports an error later on. However, searching the entire registry for `WebSetup` gave no indications as to how the download restarted after the reboot.

#### Update

That seems to have done it. I haven't had the downloader popup since I deleted the `WebSetup` directory.

Answer (score 1):

if its start automatically each boot then you should check out "msconfig" Go to run and type in msconfig. Go to start up tab then untick the one you don't want it to run each boot.

When the download windows pop up, have a look in task manager for process name. Then search that process name to see where is it located.

Comment: Sorry, neither local machine nor current user run entries point to anything. Besides, I want to get rid of all traces of the this thing.

Comment: There has to be a launcher...In what way did the window get started?